# How to add elements to Web.config at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, configurationmanager

I know that I can do something like below in order to add keys to AppSettings section:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("OS", "Linux");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

but I would like to add another node right outside `<appSettings>` node so it looks something like below:

```
<appSettings>
</appSettings>
<myCustomSetting firstValue="value1" secondValue="value2"/>
```

How can I do this in c#?

Comment: Changing web.config is not recommended and it has it it's own complications... What exactly is your requirement which forces you to modify web.config file at runtime?

Comment: Actually the settings I am adding dynamically are supposed to be pushed from elastic beanstalk (AWS) as a part of the environment variables parameter. And it will be placed inside AppSetting section of the web.config file. So I have no other option but to copy it from app settings to a new node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

var nodeRegion = xmlDoc.CreateElement("myCustomSetting ");
nodeRegion.SetAttribute("firstValue", "value1");
nodeRegion.SetAttribute("secondValue", "value2");

xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//myCustomSetting").AppendChild(nodeRegion);
xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
```

You can red here **[`Update custom configuration sections`](http://yizeng.me/2013/08/31/update-appsettings-and-custom-configuration-sections-in-appconfig-at-runtime/)**

Comment: throws object reference null error while doing : xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//myCustomSetting").AppendChild(nodeRegion);

Comment: worked after changing it to xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//configuration").AppendChild(nod‌​eRegion); since I am supposed to add my custom settings node inside configuration node.